# In Python asyncio, why does line-per-file processing blocks method?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm totally new to python's asyncio. I understand the idea, but even the most simple task won't work due to a lack of understanding on my side.

Here's my code which tries to read a file (and ultimately process each line of it) reguarily:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import aiofiles

async def main():
    async def work():
        while True:
            async with aiofiles.open('../v2.rst', 'r') as f:
                async for line in f:
                    # real work will happen here
                    pass
            print('loop')
            await asyncio.sleep(2)

    tasks = asyncio.gather(
        work(),
    )

    await asyncio.sleep(10)

    # Cancel tasks
    tasks.add_done_callback(lambda r: r.exception())
    tasks.cancel()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The `work`-function should read a file, do some line-per-line processing and then wait 2 seconds.

What happens is, that the function does "nothing". It blocks, I never see `loop` printed.

Where is my error in understanding asyncio?

Comment: I don't see where you await `tasks`. I don't think `work` is blocking anything; rather I don't think it's running.

Comment: @dirn If I remove the `open` and `for-line` I see `loop` being printed every 2 seconds.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize `gather` will automatically schedule a task for any coroutines it's given. What happens if you remove just the for loop?

Comment: @dirn I had a mistake in my code (here the file was not existing) and exceptions in async-tasks seems to be silently thrown away (even with debug=True on `run` and return_exceptions=True on `gather`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code hides the exception because the callback installed with `add_done_callback` retrieves the exception, only to immediately discard it. This prevents the (effectively unhandled) exception from getting logged by asyncio, which happens if you comment out the line with `add_done_callback`.

Also:

- the code calls `gather` without awaiting it, either immediately after the call or later.
- it unnecessarily invokes `gather` with a single coroutine. If the idea is to run the coroutine in the background, the idiomatic way to do so is with `asyncio.create_task(work())`.